# COMAdmin - force refresh of applications after install of proxy

Tags: powershell, com+

I'm programmatically installing a COM+ proxy component via Powershell, using msiexec on the msi, and then using the COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog object to set the remote server on the proxy.

The problem is that it takes a while for the newly installed proxy to be available in the "Applications" collection of COMAdminCatalog. Is there some way to force a refresh of the catalog before getting the application list?

Essentially, what I do is this:

1. `msiexec /q /i $appName.msi`
2. use the `COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog` to enumerate the apps.

```
function Set-Remote-Server-For-Complus-Application($appName, $remoteServer) {
    $comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
    $apps = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")
    $apps.Populate();
```

```
$app = $apps | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $appName}

if ($app -eq $null) {
    Write-Warning "Unable to find COM+ app ""$appName""."
    Return
}

$app.Value("ApplicationProxyServerName") = $remoteServer
$result = $apps.SaveChanges()
$apps = $null

if ($result -eq 1) {
    Write-Output "Successfully set complus remote server ""$remoteServer"" on ""$appName"""
}
```

}

The problem is that the application is not Found. If I add a `Start-Sleep -Seconds 2` between the calls, it works. But, sleeping is not good, because sometimes it might take longer than 2 seconds, sometimes it might only take 200 milliseconds, so the wait is unnecessarily long.

Is there any way to make sure that the COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog is actually updated before I try to enuerate the applications, without resorting to sleeping and just hoping for the best?

Comment: Does the RefreshComponents method on the ComAdminCatalog object resolve your issue?

Comment: No, it doesn't, unfortunately. It did seem like a good candidate, though :)